# python to c# (about server request)

Tags: c#, python, restsharp

I need to translate this python code into C#:

```
messages = { "to" :"PhoneNumber" }
body = {
    "type" : "SMS",
    "contentType" : "COMM",
    "from" : "PhoneNumber2",
    "subject" :"subject",
    "content" : "Hell world",
    "messages" : [messages]
}
body2 = json.dumps(body)
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'X-ncp-apigw-timestamp': timestamp,
    'x-ncp-iam-access-key': access_key,
    'x-ncp-apigw-signature-v2': make_signature(uri, access_key)
    }

res = requests.post(apiUrl, headers=headers, data=body2)

res.request
res.status_code
res.raise_for_status()

print(res.json())
```

So I've tried :

```
    public class themessage
    {
        public string to;
    }
    public class body
    {
        public string type;
        public string contentType;
        public string from;
        public string subject;
        public string content;
        public themessage messages;
    }


            var obj = new body
            {
                type = "SMS",
                contentType = "COMM",
                from = "PN",
                subject = "subject",
                content = "Hell World",
                messages = new themessage
                {
                    to = "PN"
                }
            };


            var client = new RestClient(apiUrl);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            request.AddHeader("X-ncp-apigw-timestamp", timestamp);
            request.AddHeader("x-ncp-iam-access-key", accessKey);
            request.AddHeader("x-ncp-apigw-signature-v2", test);
            request.AddJsonBody(obj); // **this is where I'm concerning part**
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

But, as you expected, failed to post with error message of "Not requested format" something.

Did I something wrong when making JsonBody? or posting process?

Thanks for all answers in advance!

Comment: Please post the exact error message so that people can review it and try to help you out?

Comment: The `messages` property in your python is an array (as indicated by the name). The C# code holds a single object. That might lead to errors on the server side.

Comment: I think you need to deserialize that obj using someting like newtonsoft.deserialize<body>(obj) when assigning it. Or perhaps AddJsonBody does that...

Comment: @MarkusDeibel is also right. I think you should define a class for your body, defining the properties, then assign values to it.

Comment: Could you please use Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check the actual body that's generated?

Comment: @Dave Actually its error message is written in Korean, so let me translate it into English : "status : 400, errorMessage, Requested data format is wrong"

Comment: @MarkusDeibel I thought AddJasonBody in C# code would make the body into array, was I wrong?

Comment: @Berend Thanks for your comment. I didn't know what Fiddler is (and still not sure) but I will try. It looks like some debugging tool in website... must be useful to me

Comment: As per [the RestRequest interface](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/06c264f7a6f7d696637c68193e979667de96ebb0/RestSharp/IRestRequest.cs) `AddJsonToBody` only serializes the input object. Since your object does not contain an array it won't create one in the serialized version of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my last comment on the [IRestRequest interface](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/06c264f7a6f7d696637c68193e979667de96ebb0/RestSharp/IRestRequest.cs), your class hierarchy should look similar to

```
public class themessage
{
    public string to;
}

public class body
{
    public string type;
    public string contentType;
    public string from;
    public string subject;
    public string content;
    public themessage[] messages; // <- Array here
}
```

and the object you create with it will be something like

```
var obj = new body
{
    type = "SMS",
    contentType = "COMM",
    from = "PN",
    subject = "subject",
    content = "Hell World",
    messages = new themessage[] { new themessage{to = "PN"} }
};
```

The code for the `RestClient` and `RestRquest` stays as it is.

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooooooooooo much! You saved me from 2-days of agony